# Is using OOP in C++ ever a mandate for a professional C++ programmer?

Tags: c++, oop

My title is rather self-explanatory. I've done research on that before asking this, and hope that I'll receive an informational response. I realize that, of course, it depends on the job, but as an enthusiast C++ programmer (along with a few other languages) I just don't like OOP. I don't like anything about it. So I'm wondering if I'll just have to get over it in order to move into a professional level of C++, or if I'll be okay without it.

Comment: Why you don't like OOP?

Comment: Considering the STL is OO. I would say yes.

Comment: Please see [help/dont-ask]

Comment: C++ without "OOP" is like .. C with odd differences.

Comment: OOP can be a powerful tool, but it doesn't mean you have to turn everything into a class just for the sake of overusing it. Use it whenever its practical, and don't use it if its not. Its up to you. But I suggest you get used to it, because its really useful.

Comment: Actually, the STL is mostly *not* really very object oriented. In interviews, Alex Stepanov has fairly directly commented that he never uses most "object oriented" things like inheritance and polymorphism.

Comment: If you want to "get professional" you will find yourself part of a larger software team - you better be able to understand, and build upon, the code of your colleagues. Which will, 99 times out of a 100, be full of unlikeable OOP constructs.

Comment: I'm going to take that a step further, without Objects and without Object Orientation, C++ is structurally the same as C.

Comment: @John And function overloading, and the `<<`/`>>` operators, and...

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Its OOP. `cout` is an object.

Comment: I thought this type of arguments ended 10 years ago..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write programs in C++ and do not use OOP, but professional programmer will have to deal with some one else's code all the time, including your coworkers, using third-party libraries etc. And most of the time OOP is used in C++. So yes, you need to know OOP very well and you will be forced to use it again and again if you stick to C++ in your career.

Most, but not all, of the difference between C and C++ is regarding OOP. Constructors, memory allocation, operator overloading, run-time library, templates -- all are designed with OOP in mind. Having using C++ and not mastering OOP would be difficult.

OOP is not that bad, you may think that OOP is all about:

```
class customer {
    String name, phone;
    void sellSomethingTo();
}
```

but in fact even basic parts of the language are OOP, strings, vectors, matrices, growing arrays, input/output etc.

As ptic12 mentioned, the C++ parts that make it different to C but are not OOP are namespaces, function overloading, stricter type checks, advanced variable scope and declaration.

Comment: Wrote my comment before seeing this answer - but you and I had exactly the same thought.

Comment: +1 if you're not going to use the built in OOP features of C++, you might as well just be using C.

Comment: I disagree. Even if you use only C subset of C++, it's still better to stick to C++. There are several useful features that will make your life more convenient, such as function overloading or namespaces. Also, it's harder to make mistakes, as e.g. arbitrary casts are disallowed.

Answer (score 0):

If you're a brilliant C++ programmer but just hate OOP, you could still probably get hired depending on the job. However a professional C++ programmer **should be** knowledgeable in OOP and you should make an effort to learn it.

Comment: You can't be a brilliant C++ programmer without knowing OOP ;-) Brilliant C programmer maybe, but I'm not sure, since once you start building something even moderately complex you end up doing OOP in C anyway.

Comment: An array is an object. Without OOP, there are no objects, and you surely can't be a professional without knowledge of arrays, therefore it is not possible =)

Comment: I wanted to be careful mentioning C because I didn't want to start a "C++ is just C + OOP" war =P